# which one is right?

Tags: grammar

1-do we say: **recognizing** the importance of time
or

**Recognition** the importance of time

2-It is also necessary to prepare an index for files if **its** number **increases**. or
It is also necessary to prepare an index for files if **their** number increase.
3- Divide your time **on** the importance of your tasks.
or Divide your time **according to** the importance of your tasks.

Comment: Not only is this a proofreading question, but for (1),  you haven't included enough context to decide which one is better.

Comment: the first was a title that 's way there is only this information

Comment: The fact that it's a title is in itself context.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have actually asked three questions, but of the choices presented, the correct versions are:

1. Recognizing the importance of time.
2. It is also necessary to prepare an index for files if their number increases. [It would be more common to say "an index **of** files."]
3. Divide your time according to the importance of your tasks.